# Pyspark cannot reach hive

Tags: python, hive, pyspark, hortonworks-data-platform

In short: I have a working hive on hdp3, which I cannot reach from pyspark, running under yarn (on the same hdp). How do I get pyspark to find my tables?

`spark.catalog.listDatabases()` only show default, any query run will not show in my hive logs.

This is my code, with spark 2.3.1

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
settings = []
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("Guillaume is here").setAll(settings)
spark = (
    SparkSession
    .builder
    .master('yarn')
    .config(conf=conf)
    .enableHiveSupport()
    .getOrCreate()
)
print(spark.catalog.listDatabases())
```

Note that `settings` is empty. I though it would be sufficient, because in the logs I see

> loading hive config file: file:/etc/spark2/3.0.1.0-187/0/hive-site.xml

and more interestingly

> Registering function intersectgroups io.x.x.IntersectGroups

This is a UDF I wrote and added to hive manually. This means that there is some sort of connection done.

The only output I get (except logs) is:

> [   Database(name=u'default', description=u'default database', locationUri=u'hdfs://HdfsNameService/apps/spark/warehouse')]

I understand that I should set `spark.sql.warehouse.dir` in settings. No matter if I set it to the value I find in hive-site, the path to the database I am interested in (it's not in the default location), its parent, nothing changes.

I put many other config options in settings (including thrift uris), no changes.

I have seen as well that I should copy hive-site.xml into the spark2 conf dir. I did it on all nodes of my cluster, no changes.

My command to run is:

> HDP_VERSION=3.0.1.0-187 PYTHONPATH=.:/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/:/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip SPARK_HOME=/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client HADOOP_USER_NAME=hive spark-submit --master yarn --jars /usr/hdp/current/hive_warehouse_connector/hive-warehouse-connector-assembly-1.0.0.3.0.1.0-187.jar --py-files /usr/hdp/current/hive_warehouse_connector/pyspark_hwc-1.0.0.3.0.1.0-187.zip  --files /etc/hive/conf/hive-site.xml ./subjanal/anal.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HDP 3.x, you need to use the Hive Warehouse Connector as described in [the docs](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.0.1/integrating-hive/content/hive_hivewarehousesession_api_operations.html).

Comment: I already followed this doc with the caveat that I don't have llap setup. Looks like it actually is mandatory?

Comment: Clarification--just got it confirmed that you absolutely need LLAP.

Comment: I just tested without llap and it works (at least for basic queries as `select count(*)`).  Thanks!